# Call elements off a different parent with the same ID as target object?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if this has been answered, tried looking for it but I can't seem to find one.

I've just recently started off from scratching knowing how to do HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Anyhow, I'm working on a tutorial like page of our online trading system. I've had gone from a measly large template of codes into doing it on my own once I got the grasp of it.

The page consists of multi-layered button navigations and upper - lower contents as well as tabs. sub-menu elements call other middle contents once they've been clicked. Since the middle content is off a different parent, I can't use a universal jquery function for every sub-menu elements.

Here's what I have

HTML: Sample button - I have others that follows the same - ct button, ns button, mt button...

```
<div id="" class="so button">
  <ul id="" class="somenu button check">
      <li id="sotab"/>
      <li/>
      <li/>
      <li/>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="midcontent">
   <div class="quotetab active"></div>
   <div class="uppertab">
       <span class="sotab tab"><img/></span>
   </div>
<div class="midct midct-stockinfo"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery: Universal call for buttons interaction

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".button").click(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass("pressed")) {
         $(this).removeClass("pressed");
     $(this).children().removeClass("active");
    return false;
      } else {
         $(".button").removeClass("pressed");
         $(".button").children().removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("pressed");
     $(this).children().addClass("active");
    return false;
      }
   });
```

That jquery code is what I use with the buttons on top of the page. I was planning on using the same code I've learned with the "li"'s once they've been clicked, but that would require me to nest all the elements on a single parent just to get it work, therefore, I ended up making one for each link.

```
   $(".somenu").find("li:first-child").click(function(){
      $(".tab, .quotetab, .midct").removeClass("active");
      $(".sotab").css({display: "inline-block"}).addClass("active");
      $(".midct-stockinfo").addClass("active");
   });
```

Once the li:first-child has been clicked, it would remove the focus from any active midcontent and it's tab to focus on what I've clicked.

I have that same flow of code for every li that is within menu buttons, I just change the class from .somenu to others (.ctmenu, etc) and adjust the target object accordingly.

Do you have any ideas on how I could minimize the code that I'm using?

I was able to get a snippet which works as it would read the id and look for a class that has the same name, but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
$(".button > li").click(function() {
    var containerID = this.id;
    $("." + containerID).addClass("active");
});
```

From what I understand, I'll just need to add an ID to the li's like  so that they can call the target object from the Code.

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the ID is unique. The ID would just be the same name with the class of my target object.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the `midcontent` element with descendant said class, then add active class to `tab` and `midct-stockinfo` elements within it

```
$(".button > li").click(function () {
    var $target = $('.midcontent:has(.' + this.id + ')');
    $(".tab, .quotetab, .midct").removeClass("active");

    $target.find(".sotab").css({
        display: "inline-block"
    }).addClass("active");
    $target.find(".midct-stockinfo").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it in a while.

Comment: I've been trying it and I can't seem to get it to work.